# Upload android base64 to codeigniter

Tags: java, php, android, codeigniter

Can i Upload a base64 image upload from Andoid to Codeigniter? What a simplest code?

This my code but doesnt support base64:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './asset/uspic/'; //On "userpic" upload
              $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png'; //Jpg and Png Only
              $config['max_size'] = '2048'; //2MB
              $config['max_width']  = '2048'; //max width images
              $config['max_height']  = '2048'; //max height images
              $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
              //$config['file_name'] = $prna; //set new Name
              $this->load->library('upload', $config); //load library upload
              $fnm = null;

              //Photos is detected OK
              if ($this->upload->do_upload('img')){
                //Get Filename
                $fnm = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                //Update user table on "Photo" column where Mail as ID
                $this->waterm->uptabusr(array('surel' => $mail), array('photo' => $fnm));
              }
```

Comment: You are correct in that CI upload lib won't upload a base64 image. The easiest way is to write the post stream (assuming its coming from post var) to a file. You will have to do some fancy footwork to determine if the image is an allowed type .etc. Also next time, try the search feature... your question already has a pretty good answer